# cannot get order_by :score to work with Sunspot on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, solr, sunspot

I have the following in my model:

```
searchable do
  boost { image? ? 2.0 : 1.0 }
end
```

I'm doing the following in my controller:

```
@search = Profile.solr_search do
  with :is_private, false
  without(:id).equal_to(current_profile.id)
  order_by :score, :desc
  paginate page: (params[:page] || 1), per_page: 9
end
```

I have tried `Profile.solr_reindex` in the Rails console, but the ordering of my results does not change.  `order_by :random` works, `order_by :name` works, but I can't sort by score.  It's like my document boost isn't working.  My goal is for all profiles with an image set to show up first.  What I'm getting currently is the first result is a profile with an image, then a bunch of imageless profiles, then another profile with an image.

**Edit:** thought maybe it mattered that I hadn't defined a field in the model for `image`, so I tried adding `string :image` to `Profile`.  No luck.

Comment: why trying to boost by score explicitly ? it is by default.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nuts to boosting and ordering by score.  I put the following in my `searchable` block in my model:

```
boolean :has_image, using: :image?
```

Then the following in my `solr_search` block in my controller:

```
order_by :has_image, :desc
order_by :random, :desc
```

Now I get all the profiles with images first, in some random order, followed by all the profiles without images, also in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to influence the scoring based on your flag like this:

```
@search = Profile.solr_search do
  boost(10) { with(:has_image, true)}
  ...
end
```